# ImageView Wont Appear In Navigation Drawer Toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Im using a Navigation Drawer and I want the logo of my App to appear in the center of my Navigation Drawer toolbar. I've tried alot of solutions online but my logo appears in the preview but when I run the app, it's not in my toolbar. 
This is my App Bar layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logoActionBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/actionbarlogo" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_home_customer" />
```

This is the main activity of my navigation drawer:

```
    public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_customer);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //  toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.actionbarlogo);
//
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Constants cnst = new Constants();
        cnst.getNearbyusers(33.522212, 73.091904);

        // getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo_final);
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        //  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        View hView = nvDrawer.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView nav_username = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.fullNameUser);
        TextView nav_emailuser = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.emailUser);
        ImageView nav_profilepic = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.ProfilePhoto);

        Fragment home = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FM
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_layout, home)
                .commit();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("HouseKeepingtg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String username = prefs.getString("fName", null);
        String email = prefs.getString("Email", null);
        String profilepic = prefs.getString("Profilepic", null);
        nav_username.setText(username);
        nav_emailuser.setText(email);
        if (profilepic != null)
            nav_profilepic.setImageBitmap(decodeBase64(profilepic));

        Log.v("UserData", username + email);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_display_worker_list:
                fragmentClass = DisplayWorkersActivity.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_map:
                fragmentClass = MapsActivity.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                fragmentClass = SettingsFragment.class;
                break;
//            case R.id.nav_update_profile:
//                    Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, SignupRetailer.class);
//                    startActivity(intent);
//
//                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final Fragment finalFragment = fragment;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_layout, finalFragment).commit();

            }

        }, 250);


        // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        // Set action bar title
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        // Close the navigation drawer
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();


    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_customer, menu);
        return true;
    }

//    @Override
//    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
//        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
//        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
//        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
//        int id = item.getItemId();
//
//        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
//        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
//            return true;
//        }
//
//        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
//    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(input, 0);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
    }


    public void clearStack() {
/*
* Here we are clearing back stack fragment entries
*/
        int backStackEntry = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        if (backStackEntry > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < backStackEntry; i++) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            }
        }

/*
* Here we are removing all the fragment that are shown here
*/
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() != null && getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size(); i++) {
                Fragment mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(i);
                if (mFragment != null) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mFragment).commit();
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: is the value of `String profilepic = prefs.getString("Profilepic", null);` valid at runtime?

Comment: @Chisko yes it's all valid, the only problem is imageView appearing on the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Though toolbars is a  ViewGroup, you don't add sub views to it like a layout in XML. You either

- add specific XML attributes to the actual toolbar, like `android.support.v7.appcompat:logo` and others
- use code to add view to it, like `setLogo()` and other toolbar functions.

You can read it all in the docs.

Comment: but setLogo() doesn't centralize the logo, i want it to be in the middle of the bar

Comment: You can try the ViewGroup `addView` method, but it will probably mess up the whole toolbar. You can also play around with the ContentInsets of the toolbar, there are many functions for it. If you need, you can just skip the toolbar, and create a view that mimics the toolbar functionality that you need.

Comment: yes i thought of that but will it have the navigation drawer functionality?